# What is the difference between set and hashset in C++ STL?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, set, hashset

When should I choose one over the other?
Are there any pointers that you would recommend for using the right STL containers?

Comment: There is no `hashset` in STL. There will be `unordered_set` in C++ (hopefully) next year.

Comment: Talking about this http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_set.html

Comment: There is a discussion related to this here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222658/multiset-map-and-hash-map-complexity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222658/multiset-map-and-hash-map-complexity) Edit: Adam Rosenfield's answer on that question lays out the big-O for each.

Comment: @mkal: That's not part of the standard STL. `hash_set` is an extension.

Comment: What is the "standard STL"?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`hash_set` is an extension that is not part of the C++ standard. Lookups should be O(1) rather than O(log n) for `set`, so it will be faster in most circumstances.

Another difference will be seen when you iterate through the containers. `set` will deliver the contents in sorted order, while `hash_set` will be essentially random (Thanks Lou Franco).

Edit: The C++11 update to the C++ standard introduced [`unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) which should be preferred instead of `hash_set`. The performance will be similar and is guaranteed by the standard. The "unordered" in the name stresses that iterating it will produce results in no particular order.

Answer (score 23):

`stl::set` is implemented as a binary search tree.
`hashset` is implemented as a hash table.

The main issue here is that many people use `stl::set` thinking it is a hash table with look-up of O(1), which it isn't, and doesn't have.  It really has O(log(n)) for look-ups.  Other than that, read about binary trees vs hash tables to get a better idea of the data structures.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? -- a red-black tree is a kind of binary search tree, and the spec doesn't say it has to be red-black -- it just set big-O parameters for the operations.

Comment: @LouFranco: Probably because it discusses [possible (likely!)] implementations rather than standard-mandated behaviour/semantics.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing to keep in mind is that with hash_set you have to provide the hash function, whereas a set only requires a comparison function ('<') which is easier to define (and predefined for native types).

Comment: There are hash functions for native types too.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think anyone has answered the other part of the question yet.

The reason to use hash_set or unordered_set is the usually O(1) lookup time. I say usually because every so often, depending on implementation, a hash may have to be copied to a larger hash array, or a hash bucket may end up containing thousands of entries.

The reason to use a set is if you often need the largest or smallest member of a set. A hash has no order so there is no quick way to find the smallest item. A tree has order, so largest or smallest is very quick. O(log n) for a simple tree, O(1) if it holds pointers to the ends.

Comment: an unordered_set lookup or insertion will be from O(1) to O(n).  There are no guarantees it will be closer to O(1).  A (ordered) set lookup will be up to O(log n).  It does not mean it will be closer to O(n) most of the time (like you hinted with your comment about the first and last possibly taking O(1)).

Your comment about rehashing could use some clarification.  Implementations are not forced to rehash when a lookup is done.  A lookup would take O(n) when a node contains all entries and thus a linear lookup needs to be performed.

Answer (score 2):

A hash_set would be implemented by a hash table, which has mostly O(1) operations, whereas a set is implemented by a tree of some sort (AVL, red black, etc.) which have O(log n) operations, but are in sorted order.

Edit: I had written that trees are O(n).  That's completely wrong.