# a hash set can find the smallest or largest element with O(1)?

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap, hashtable, hashset

I need to understand the architecture and functions of hash set very well.

Compared with STL::set, what is the advantage of hash set compared with STL::set ? I think the O(1) time to do search. If this is true, why not to use hash table ? Their difference is duplicated element ? or others ?

For STL::set, the search time of smallest/largest is also O(1), because it has been ordered.

A hash set is not a binary search tree, how to find the smallest or largest element with O(1) ?

After reading 
[What is the difference between set and hashset in C++ STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518305/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-hashset-in-c-stl)

I cannot find the answer .

My idea:

When should use hash set not hash table ?

STL::set is ordered set. So, it is O(1) to get smallest/largest element.

What if for hash set ? it is ordered ?

thanks

Comment: What makes you think you *can* find the largest or smallest element in O(1)?

Comment: cant understand, you want only smallest/largest elements in O(1) or lookup in O(1) or both to be O(1) ?

Comment: How does a hash set work? (It is essentially the same as how a hash table works.) That is the answer. The first answer in the linked post answers the questions here: "essentially random", "[not] ordered".

Answer (score 3):

> A hash set is not a binary search tree, how to find the smallest or largest element with O(1)?

This is exactly one of the key differences: you can't find the smallest/largest element in a hash set in constant time. You can, of course, do it in `O(n)` time by scanning the entire set.

Another key difference is that iterating over a hash set does not return the elements in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

A hash set is basically a hash table without stored values (only keys), and `std::set` in C++ are implemented as a balanced binary search tree.

You should read on the differences in some algorithm/computer science book, as you seem to have some basic misconceptions, for example, in a binary search tree the cost of finding the smallest/largest element is logarithmic `O(log N)`, not constant `O(1)`.

Depending on the operations that you need to perform most often, either data structure will be more appropriate. If you need to find the smallest element quite often, then a `std::set` will perform the operation in `O(log N)`, but with a hash table you will need to check all elements and that means linear time `O(N)`. If on the other hand that operation is not common and regular lookups (is element a in the set?) are more common, the constant time lookup of a hash set will be better than `O(log N)` lookup in a set.

Comment: Why would it not be O(1) to find the smallest/ largest element in a `std::set`? `set.begin()` and `set.rbegin()` are your friends.

Comment: @Xeo, unless the set contains a specific optimization a tree might require O(log n) to find the first or last element.

Comment: @Xeo, you might be right - according to this reference, set.begin and set.rbegin are required to have constant complexity. I'm not sure whether to trust the reference though. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/begin/

Comment: @Mark: At least one recent standard draft requires constant complexity for `begin` and `end` for all containers.

Comment: @Mark: Both C++03 and C++11 standards require constant complexity in the `c.begin()` and `c.rbegin()` for container and reversible container requirements (see C++03 §23.1 p5 & p9 and C++11 §23.2.1 p4 & p9 for requirements, aswell as C++03 §23.3.3 p2 and C++11 §23.4.6.1 p2 for which requirements `std::set` satisfies).

Comment: @Xeo: I have not looked in detail the new standard. The `O(log N)` time is the standard time to find the first/last element in a balanced binary tree. Of course, an implementation can decide to cache those two specific values --and it seems that the standard mandates it.