# Why is the complexity of the C++ STL map container O(log(n))?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, dictionary

For C++ STL containers such as `vector` and `list`, the complexity of finding elements and inserting or removing them is self-explanatory. However, for the `map` container, even though I know from my reading that the access and insertion complexity/performance is O(log(n)), I can't work out *why*. I clearly don't understand maps as much as I need to, so some enlightenment on this topic would be very much appreciated.

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/222674/1025391

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The elements of a map or set are contained in a tree structure; every time you examine a node of the tree, you determine if the element you're trying to find/insert is less than or greater than the node. The number of times you need to do this (for a properly balanced tree) is log2(N) because each comparison throws out half of the possibilities.

Comment: Thank you, Mark, your answer is just what I needed.

Comment: @EdKing, take a look at [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_black_tree). They're usually used to implement std::map.

Answer (score 1):

As slavik262 points, maps are usually implemented with red-black-trees, which are self-balanced.
Check the complexity of a red-black-tree for example in the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_black_tree)
I don't know any implementation of a map with a binary tree; if Mark Ransom knows one, I'd be pleased to know which one.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that a red-black tree *is* a binary tree, just with some invariants on the shape of the tree and re-balancing operations to maintain these during insertion and deletion.