# Fastest way to store internally sorted map elements

Tags: c++, algorithm

Are there any ordered container that allow O(n) in-ordered deletion and traversal?  I'm trying to do the following:

```
Hello  -> 1,2,3,4,5,6
Hello1 -> 24,15,13,10,8,7
```

I need to be able to insert and delete continuously from Hello or Hello1 as quickly as possible.  I was thinking of using a priority queue, but each time I want to delete I spend O(logn) adjusting, so n deletions will cost me O(nlogn) time to keep the internal structure ordered.  Are there any data structures that can accomplish this task in O(n) time?

Comment: How about a `std::set`, or `std::multiset`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/222658/1175253

Comment: I should have mentioned that I also need to update values periodically.  With a set or multiset this is more difficult to accomplish, as I understand.

Comment: Can you clarify what 'but each time I want to delete I spend O(logn) adjusting, so n deletions will cost me O(nlogn) time to keep the internal structure ordered' exactly means? Do you want to delete a whole number of items all at once?

Comment: The priority queues internal structure has to be maintained when a delete happens (to keep order), which takes O(logn) time.  Thus, if I delete n separate elements from a priority queue I'll spend O(nlogn) doing it.

Comment: @BobJohn when you modify values, are you identifying the value to modify by *index* or *value*?

Comment: You can `const_cast` to modify a set if you can guarentee the ordering is correct.

Comment: @DrewDormann by index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `std::vector`, with some sorting pegged on top; don't use `std::sort` every time - use a merge sort.

Complexity is important, but when the data set is small the time taken for memory allocation and cache misses will far out way this. Generally, profile it, but I would conject in this case a `vector` will be fine.

Think carefully about if you need to keep the structure always sorted; can you insert a number of items before resorting? What about 2 vectors and merging on a lookup? Think carefully about your algorithms; you can delete any number of items in `O(n)`, for instance.

Comment: The data set is not small, this was just an example of what I wanted.

Comment: How "not small" is not small?

Comment: Millions of values.  I don't necessarily need all of the values sorted at all times, but rather I always need the maximum or minimum element at any time.

Comment: I'm sure you can figure out some algorithms to keep the complexity down if you only need min/max; maybe using a `deque`-like structure.

Comment: I need the max/min even when I delete elements, though.

Comment: Keep the data in `log n` buckets, keep the first and last sorted.

Comment: Scrap that; `sqrt(n)` buckets.