# R - Create multiple scenario combinations

Tags: r, combinations

I have four (partially overlapping) groups of eight unique applicants that have applied for 20%, 30%, 40%, and 50% of the work I have to assign:

```
g20 <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
g30 <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
g40 <- c("c","d","e","f","g","h")
g50 <- c("e","f","g","h")
```

Because I can only award the work in these four increments and I have to choose no fewer than two people and no more than four, I have six scenarios for awarding 100% of the work:

1. 50/50
2. 50/30/20
3. 40/40/20
4. 40/30/30
5. 40/20/20/20
6. 30/30/20/20

For each scenario, I need to find all the possible combinations (without replacement) for awarding the work to the applicants in the corresponding groups.

I can easily enough accomplish this for the first scenario using `t(combn(g50,2))` but I am unsure how to handle the other scenarios where I have to pull combinations from different vectors AND ensure an applicant is only selected only once in any given combination. The output needs to be the actual combinations, not just the number of combinations.

Using R, how do I do get these combinations pulling from four different groups and (using scenario 5 as an example) ensure that "cdef", "cedf", "cfed", "cfde" etc. are all treated as the same result?

Is this possible?

Comment: can you share with us the actual dimension of your problem?

Comment: Are we to understand that applicant `a` is willing to work 20% or 30%, but not 40% or 50%? I used that constraint for my answer, but I'm not certain if that was the correct interpretation.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Some people only have the capacity to do smaller portions of work, others only want to do a lot of work. Yet others are willing to do any work they can get.

Comment: Would it not be allowed to assign work 20% each to five individuals, eg abcde or bcdef? You didn't include it in your six scenarios but I wasn't sure if that was intentional or not.

Comment: It was intentional. Having four or fewer individuals makes it easier to manage and control the workflow, therefore 20/20/20/20/20 is not a valid option for me.

Comment: @user10892378 so you want to also know which applicants has been assigned to which portions of work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also creating all possible combinations like Jon Spring's solution but using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package and removing dupe applicant.

If your real-life dimensions are per OP, you can consider expanding to all possible combinations and remove rows where an applicant is duplicated:

```
library(data.table)

g20 <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
g30 <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
g40 <- c("c","d","e","f","g","h")
g50 <- c("e","f","g","h")

scen <- paste0("g", c(30, 30, 20, 20))
allcombi <- do.call(CJ, mget(scen))
setnames(allcombi, paste0("V", 1L:length(allcombi)))

#remove rows with applicants that are repeated in different columns
nodupe <- allcombi[
    allcombi[, .I[anyDuplicated(unlist(.SD)) == 0L], 
        by=1:allcombi[,.N]]$V1]

#sort within columns with the same percentage of work
for(cols in split(names(nodupe), scen))
    nodupe[, (cols) := sort(.SD), by=seq_len(nodupe[,.N]), .SDcols=cols]

#remove identical combinations
ans <- unique(nodupe)
setnames(ans, scen)[]
```

output:

```
     g30 g30 g20 g20
  1:   a   b   c   d
  2:   a   b   c   e
  3:   a   b   c   f
  4:   a   b   d   e
  5:   a   b   d   f
 ---                
221:   g   h   c   e
222:   g   h   c   f
223:   g   h   d   e
224:   g   h   d   f
225:   g   h   e   f
```

---

Code & results from running for all 6 scenarios:

```
scenarios <- list(c(50,50), 
    c(50,30,20), 
    c(40,40,20), 
    c(40,30,30), 
    c(40,20,20,20), 
    c(30,30,20,20))

lapply(scenarios, 
    function(scen) {
        scen <- paste0("g", scen)
        allcombi <- do.call(CJ, mget(scen, envir=.GlobalEnv))
        setnames(allcombi, paste0("V", 1L:length(allcombi)))

        nodupe <- allcombi[
            allcombi[, .I[anyDuplicated(unlist(.SD)) == 0L], 
                by=1:allcombi[,.N]]$V1]

        for(cols in split(names(nodupe), scen))
            nodupe[, (cols) := sort(.SD), by=seq_len(nodupe[,.N]), .SDcols=cols]

        ans <- unique(nodupe)
        setnames(ans, scen)[]
})
```

output:

```
[[1]]
   g50 g50
1:   e   f
2:   e   g
3:   e   h
4:   f   g
5:   f   h
6:   g   h

[[2]]
     g50 g30 g20
  1:   e   a   b
  2:   e   a   c
  3:   e   a   d
  4:   e   a   f
  5:   e   b   a
 ---            
128:   h   g   b
129:   h   g   c
130:   h   g   d
131:   h   g   e
132:   h   g   f

[[3]]
    g40 g40 g20
 1:   c   d   a
 2:   c   d   b
 3:   c   d   e
 4:   c   d   f
 5:   c   e   a
 6:   c   e   b
 7:   c   e   d
 8:   c   e   f
 9:   c   f   a
10:   c   f   b
11:   c   f   d
12:   c   f   e
13:   c   g   a
14:   c   g   b
15:   c   g   d
16:   c   g   e
17:   c   g   f
18:   c   h   a
19:   c   h   b
20:   c   h   d
21:   c   h   e
22:   c   h   f
23:   d   e   a
24:   d   e   b
25:   d   e   c
26:   d   e   f
27:   d   f   a
28:   d   f   b
29:   d   f   c
30:   d   f   e
31:   d   g   a
32:   d   g   b
33:   d   g   c
34:   d   g   e
35:   d   g   f
36:   d   h   a
37:   d   h   b
38:   d   h   c
39:   d   h   e
40:   d   h   f
41:   e   f   a
42:   e   f   b
43:   e   f   c
44:   e   f   d
45:   e   g   a
46:   e   g   b
47:   e   g   c
48:   e   g   d
49:   e   g   f
50:   e   h   a
51:   e   h   b
52:   e   h   c
53:   e   h   d
54:   e   h   f
55:   f   g   a
56:   f   g   b
57:   f   g   c
58:   f   g   d
59:   f   g   e
60:   f   h   a
61:   f   h   b
62:   f   h   c
63:   f   h   d
64:   f   h   e
65:   g   h   a
66:   g   h   b
67:   g   h   c
68:   g   h   d
69:   g   h   e
70:   g   h   f
    g40 g40 g20

[[4]]
     g40 g30 g30
  1:   c   a   b
  2:   c   a   d
  3:   c   a   e
  4:   c   a   f
  5:   c   a   g
 ---            
122:   h   d   f
123:   h   d   g
124:   h   e   f
125:   h   e   g
126:   h   f   g

[[5]]
    g40 g20 g20 g20
 1:   c   a   b   d
 2:   c   a   b   e
 3:   c   a   b   f
 4:   c   a   d   e
 5:   c   a   d   f
 6:   c   a   e   f
 7:   c   b   d   e
 8:   c   b   d   f
 9:   c   b   e   f
10:   c   d   e   f
11:   d   a   b   c
12:   d   a   b   e
13:   d   a   b   f
14:   d   a   c   e
15:   d   a   c   f
16:   d   a   e   f
17:   d   b   c   e
18:   d   b   c   f
19:   d   b   e   f
20:   d   c   e   f
21:   e   a   b   c
22:   e   a   b   d
23:   e   a   b   f
24:   e   a   c   d
25:   e   a   c   f
26:   e   a   d   f
27:   e   b   c   d
28:   e   b   c   f
29:   e   b   d   f
30:   e   c   d   f
31:   f   a   b   c
32:   f   a   b   d
33:   f   a   b   e
34:   f   a   c   d
35:   f   a   c   e
36:   f   a   d   e
37:   f   b   c   d
38:   f   b   c   e
39:   f   b   d   e
40:   f   c   d   e
41:   g   a   b   c
42:   g   a   b   d
43:   g   a   b   e
44:   g   a   b   f
45:   g   a   c   d
46:   g   a   c   e
47:   g   a   c   f
48:   g   a   d   e
49:   g   a   d   f
50:   g   a   e   f
51:   g   b   c   d
52:   g   b   c   e
53:   g   b   c   f
54:   g   b   d   e
55:   g   b   d   f
56:   g   b   e   f
57:   g   c   d   e
58:   g   c   d   f
59:   g   c   e   f
60:   g   d   e   f
61:   h   a   b   c
62:   h   a   b   d
63:   h   a   b   e
64:   h   a   b   f
65:   h   a   c   d
66:   h   a   c   e
67:   h   a   c   f
68:   h   a   d   e
69:   h   a   d   f
70:   h   a   e   f
71:   h   b   c   d
72:   h   b   c   e
73:   h   b   c   f
74:   h   b   d   e
75:   h   b   d   f
76:   h   b   e   f
77:   h   c   d   e
78:   h   c   d   f
79:   h   c   e   f
80:   h   d   e   f
    g40 g20 g20 g20

[[6]]
     g30 g30 g20 g20
  1:   a   b   c   d
  2:   a   b   c   e
  3:   a   b   c   f
  4:   a   b   d   e
  5:   a   b   d   f
 ---                
221:   g   h   c   e
222:   g   h   c   f
223:   g   h   d   e
224:   g   h   d   f
225:   g   h   e   f
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If you sort every row and remove duplicates, you only get 70 combinations. Remember order doesn't matter. Again, I'm not sure.

Comment: @JosephWood, thanks, you are correct. I have group by cols, sort and remove dupes now.

Comment: I still think this approach is incorrect. First off, this still produces duplicate results. Take for example scenario 2, there should be 96 results : `length(unique(apply(t(apply(expand.grid(g50, g30, g20), 1, sort)), 1, paste0, collapse=""))) [1] 96`. And if you take your result (the answer by @JonSpring as well), sort each row and remove duplicates, you only get 52 results: `nrow(unique(t(apply(as.matrix(ans2[[2]]), 1, sort))))` (`ans2` is the output of your `lapply(scenarios, ...`).

Comment: when I run `(unique(apply(t(apply(expand.grid(g50, g30, g20), 1, sort)), 1, paste0, collapse="")))`, the first element is `aae` which is not correct.

Comment: I think that is acceptable in this case as `a` is in both `g20` and `g30`. The point is that we don't produce `aae` again (which we won't because there is only one such possibility). A better example would be like `eef`. Since `e` and `f` occur in `g50`, `g30` and `g20`, it is possible to produce `eef`, `efe`, and `fee`.

Comment: One thing you should note is that this appears to be a special case of combination with repetition. There was a great post addressing this very problem. See this question: [Picking unordered combinations from pools with overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51834467/4408538). Note the answer is far from trivial.

Comment: Never mind, I just reread where the OP states that they are looking for combinations without replacement as it would be impossible for an applicant to appear twice in one scenario. Still though, this is a neat problem.

Comment: I agree with your comments. the case where you brought up is really interesting. sounds like a good qn to post as well. OP is not very clear about applicant performing 2 portions of the work. I would use `combn` with each percentage of work in your case

Comment: I will say one last thing. Look at your output for `[[3]]`. Line 54 is `54:   e   h   f` and line 64 `64:   f   h   e`. This is to be avoided. I'm not familiar enough with `data.table` to give any advice on how to get around this.

Comment: yeah, we can also remove duplicated rows after sorting each row but I don't think it will achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT -- updated my response based on closer reading of OP. Now identifying how many distinct teams can be formed, regardless of the permutations of how the work can be divided among them.

Yes! This is by no means the most elegant or efficient solution, but it is possible. It takes about 1 second with this data, but it will be slower if you have real data that is more complicated.

First I establish the possibilities for each applicant. I think it makes more intuitive sense to lay it out this way, because we need to make one assignment (including the possibility of zero) for each applicant.

```
a <- c(0, 20, 30)
b <- c(0, 20, 30)
c <- c(0, 20, 30, 40)
d <- c(0, 20, 30, 40)
e <- c(0, 20, 30, 40, 50)
f <- c(0, 20, 30, 40, 50)
g <- c(0,     30, 40, 50)
h <- c(0,     30, 40, 50)
```

Then I enumerate all the possibilities of assigning the work, using `expand.grid`, and then filter to only include the ones where 100% of work gets done.

```
library(tidyverse)
soln_with_permutations <- expand.grid(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) %>%
  # the Applicants come in as Var1, Var2... here, will rename below
  as.tibble() %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>% # This number tracks each row / potential solution

  # gather into long format to make summing simpler
  gather(applicant, assignment, -rowname) %>%
  # rename Var1 as "a", Var2 as "b", and so on.
  mutate(applicant = str_sub(applicant, start = -1) %>% as.integer %>% letters[.]) %>%
  
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  # keep only solutions adding to 100%
  filter(sum(assignment) == 100) %>%
  # keep only solutions involving four or fewer applicants
  filter(sum(assignment > 0) <= 4) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Each `rowname` describes a distinct solution in terms of how the work is divided among the applicants, but many are permutations where the work is allocated differently among the same teams. To see how many different teams are formed, and how many different scenarios could work for that team, I label each solution with the team (labeled alphabetically) and the scenario (labeled by descending share).

```
soln_distinct_teams <- soln_with_permutations %>%
  filter(assignment > 0) %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  # Get team composition, alphabetical
  mutate(team = paste0(applicant, collapse = "")) %>%
  # Get allocation structure, descending
  arrange(-assignment) %>%
  mutate(allocation = paste0(assignment, collapse = "/")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  
  # Distinct teams / allocations only
  distinct(team, allocation) %>%
  arrange(allocation, team) %>%
  mutate(soln_num = row_number()) %>%
  
  # select(soln_num, team, allocation) %>%
  spread(allocation, soln_num)
```

Each row shows one of the 132 different teams of 2-4 applicants which could be created, and across the columns we see the different scenarios that could apply to that team in at least one permutation.

```
# A tibble: 132 x 7
   team  `30/30/20/20` `40/20/20/20` `40/30/30` `40/40/20` `50/30/20` `50/50`
   <chr>         <int>         <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>   <int>
 1 abc              NA            NA        126         NA         NA      NA
 2 abcd              1            71         NA         NA         NA      NA
 3 abce              2            72         NA         NA         NA      NA
 4 abcf              3            73         NA         NA         NA      NA
 5 abcg              4            74         NA         NA         NA      NA
 6 abch              5            75         NA         NA         NA      NA
 7 abd              NA            NA        127         NA         NA      NA
 8 abde              6            76         NA         NA         NA      NA
 9 abdf              7            77         NA         NA         NA      NA
10 abdg              8            78         NA         NA         NA      NA
# ... with 122 more rows
```

Comment: I just reread the question and noticed the requirement to use four or fewer people. To do so, we should filter out solution 6 above.

Comment: This produces undesired results. If you examine your output, you will see that there are results like `a b c` and `a c b` (i.e. permutations).

Comment: You have many duplicate (speaking in combinations) results. Try `length(unique(apply(solution, 1, function(x) {
    paste0(letters[sort(which(x > 0))], collapse = "")
})))`... it returns 138 (not 645).

Comment: There are not any duplicated assignments, if you count different allotments of hours among the same team as different solutions. `solution %>% distinct(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)` is still 645 rows.

Comment: Taking your output as an example with scenario 6: `30/30/20/20`, you have `2      54    30    30    20    20` which maps to `a b c d`, `3      60    30    20    30    20` which maps to `a c b d` and  `4      62    20    30    30    20 ` which maps to `c a b d`. This is specifically prohibited by the OP _""cdef", "cedf", "cfed", "cfde" etc. are all treated as the same result"_. I suggest you take a look at the output of what I posted above: `apply(solution[,-1], 1, function(x) { paste0(letters[sort(which(x > 0))], collapse = "") })`. Remember order doesn't matter with combinations.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me. For some reason I read OP multiple times thinking the idea was to avoid solutions where a set of applicants are assigned the same hours but this solution is *presented* in different order. Now updated to show there are only 132 "teams" of 2-4 which can be created, which matches @chinsoon12 's result

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help on this one! chinsoon12's solution was the most useful for me to build off of. As noted, this solution was still returning some duplicates (in the 40/40/20 or 40/30/30 scenarios it was not removing duplicates where the percentage appeared twice in the scenario).

While perhaps not the most elegant solution, I modified chinsoon12's solution. Using 40/40/20 as an example, I first created all possible combinations of 40/40 then created the combinations of 40/40 and 20. I was then able to accurately remove the duplicates.

```
# Create 40/40 combos
combs_40 <- t(combn(g40,2))
c40 <- paste0(combs_40[,1],combs_40[,2])

# Create combos of 40/40 and 20
scen <- c("c40","g20")
allcombi <- do.call(CJ, mget(scen, envir=.GlobalEnv))
allcombi <- as.data.frame(allcombi)

# Split into cols
x <- t(as.data.frame(strsplit(allcombi$c40,split="")))
allcombi <- as.data.table(cbind(x[,1],x[,2],allcombi$g20))
setnames(allcombi, paste0("V", 1L:length(allcombi)))

# Remove rows with applicants that are repeated in different columns
nodupe <- allcombi[
  allcombi[, .I[anyDuplicated(unlist(.SD)) == 0L], 
           by=1:allcombi[,.N]]$V1]
# Redefine scen
scen <- c("g40","g40","g20")

# Sort within columns with the same percentage of work
for(cols in split(names(nodupe), scen))
  nodupe[, (cols) := sort(.SD), by=seq_len(nodupe[,.N]), .SDcols=cols]

# Set names, write results
setnames(nodupe, scen)[]
results_404020 <- nodupe
```

Comment: I'm still a little confused. If you look at your output, there are still duplicate values. Take for example the 3rd (`c   d   e`), 7th (`c   e   d`), and 11th row (`d   e   c`) from `results_404020`. They are all permutations, which I thought was to be avoided.

Comment: Yes, while those are permutations, you have to account for the difference in the percentages. If I were awarding one third of the work to each, you would be correct, as any permutation would have the same end result (each applicant gets 33.3%). Here though, the first two are getting 40% each, and the last 20%. Therefore cde and ced are different, but cde and dce are the same.